# Create a dynamic grid view with varying cell size in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I want to create a grid view with varying cell size. But due to the inbuilt windows feature in which the cells adjust themselves in the row, I get the following result.

[image]

But I want to get a grid with a feature similar to staggered grid in android as given in this link:

https://dzone.com/articles/how-implement-staggered-grid

Is there a method to do this in WP8.1 programming?

Comment: May be you need variableSizedWrapgrid  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.variablesizedwrapgrid

Comment: I tried to use variableSizedWrapgrid. But I am getting the same result as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

In xaml Use ItemsControl that Represents a control that can be used to present a collection of items.

Create a new Panel that we can use for any ItemsControl. for more information refer this link: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/02/20/Creating-a-WrapPanel-for-your-Windows-Runtime-apps.aspx

write a class in xaml.cs as follows.

```
public class WrapPanel : Panel
{

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        // Just take up all of the width
        Size finalSize = new Size { Width = availableSize.Width };

        double x = 0;
        double rowHeight = 0d;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            // Tell the child control to determine the size needed
            child.Measure(availableSize);

            x += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            if (x > availableSize.Width)
            {
                // this item will start the next row
                x = child.DesiredSize.Width;

                // adjust the height of the panel
                finalSize.Height += rowHeight;
                rowHeight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the tallest item
                rowHeight = Math.Max(child.DesiredSize.Height, rowHeight);
            }
        }

        // Just in case we only had one row
        if (finalSize.Height == 0)
        {
            finalSize.Height = rowHeight;
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        Rect finalRect = new Rect(0, 0, (finalSize.Width / 2) - 10, finalSize.Height);

        double EvenItemHeight = 0;
        double OddItemHeight = 0;
        int itemNumber = 1;
        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            if (itemNumber % 2 == 0)
            {
                finalRect.X = (finalSize.Width / 2);
                finalRect.Y = EvenItemHeight;
                EvenItemHeight += Children[itemNumber - 1].DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                finalRect.X = 0;
                finalRect.Y = OddItemHeight;
                OddItemHeight += Children[itemNumber - 1].DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            itemNumber++;
            child.Arrange(finalRect);
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

}
```

StaggerGrid.xaml code is as follows:
xmlns:local="using:StaggerGridSample.Views"// namespace of class WrapPanel

```
<Grid>
        <ScrollViewer >
            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding StrList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <local:WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Background="Red" 
                            Width="185"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Margin="0,0,6,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   FontSize="20"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```